# Mathematics paper in arXiv general math section

Tags: publications, mathematics, arxiv

When does a math research paper get uploaded into arXiv math.GM, the general mathematics section? I have seen some papers in math.GM claiming to have solved some open problem (which are obviously wrong). Besides this what would be the other reasons?

Comment: Afaik, this is usually done by people who barely know what they are doing. A serious mathematician will avoid math.GM.

Answer (score 14):

As far as I know, this may happen in two ways:

1. The author (or authors) of the paper barely knows what they are doing, hence, cannot figure out what kind of math category their work belongs to and use GM. A variation on this theme is that they wrongly assume that classifying their work as GM, increases the readership (in fact, the opposite is true).
2. The decision to **reclassify** the work as GM is made by arXiv moderators, who sense that the paper is junk but are not entirely sure; hence, instead of rejecting the paper outright, they do the reclassification (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv) Wikipedia article about the arXiv).

A serious mathematician will not use the GM category.

Comment: That last is a bit strong. There are serious mathematicians who do write for a general audience. Just as there are in physics, etc.

Comment: @Buffy: Of course, just they would not use the GM arXiv category (as things currently stand, I am not talking about papers from 20-30 years ago).

Comment: @Buffy Even writing for a general audience normally involves some specific mathematics. Of course, writing about e.g. what mathematics is can fit the "general mathematics" tag, but when serious mathematicians do that sort of thing they tend to put it in math.HO ("history and overview") instead.

Comment: For what it's worth, the converse of 2. happened to me when I uploaded my first paper to arXiv as a beginning PhD student 9-10 years ago. It was about totally ordered (algebraic) semigroups, which is quite of a niche topic (and it stemmed from my Bachelor's thesis and wasn't really related to the field my PhD advisor was used to). It didn't seem to fit any of the algebraic categories but, to my unexperienced self, didn't really feel like "analysis" either - so I selected "GM". The arXiv moderators were kind enough to reclassify it as "Classical Analysis and ODEs".

Comment: @JochenGlueck: also could have been Rings and Algebras (which includes semigroups).

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Yes, indeed. I guess my reasoning back then was that there was too much "topology on the real line" in the paper to classify it as "Ring and Algebras", but (a priori) too little structure from the real field to classify it as "analysis". The bottom line is, of course, that I misunderstood "general mathematics" as a category for papers that are "in the middle" between two other categories, rather than a category for dubious or crank papers. ;-)

Comment: I classified my paper as Classical Analysis and ODEs and they put it in GM. Now I understand why they did that;-; I did realize that the way I wrote my paper made them think it was junk right away. I hope a new referee sees the update and realizes that it isn't as bad as they thought ;-;